# How can I retrieve a list of field for all objects in Django?

Tags: django

I want to retrieve a list of all of the values for one field from a query in django. For example, I have a query of users, but rather than a queryset (or list) of user objects, I want a list just the usernames (strings). In a sense this is asking to restrict only to one column of data.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Have you tried

```
list(User.objects.all().values_list('username', flat=True))
```

> If you only pass in a single field, you can also pass in the flat parameter. If True, this     will mean the returned results are single values, rather than one-tuples. Additionally, casting it to a list makes the returned value a list instead of a queryset

Comment: It actually returns a QuerySet object not a list and hence does not support item assignment.

Comment: Something funny happened on my end. I wanted to get a list of all the fields from something that wasn't the `User` object. I put it in and got a `django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword '' into field. Choices are:` error but still showed all of the different fields for that model.... I'll take what I can get.

Answer (score 13):

To get the list of usernames:

```
>>> User.objects.all().values('username')
>>> [{'username': u'u1'}, {'username': u'u2'}]

>>> User.objects.all().values_list('username')
>>> [(u'u1',), (u'u2',)]
```

If you want just strings, a list comprehension can do the trick:

```
>>> usr_names = User.objects.all().values('username')
>>> [u['username'] for u in usr_names]
>>> [u'u1', u'u2']
```

Using `values_list`:

```
>>> usr_names = User.objects.all().values_list('username')
>>> [u[0] for u in usr_names]
>>> [u'u1', u'u2']
```

Comment: Close; but this gives me a list of dictionaries (actually a ValuesQuerySet, but...) If I use values_list I get a list of tuples which is closer still, but I'd really like a straight list e.g. [u'u1', u'u2']

Comment: You're right. I edited the answer. I prefer values() btw, don't know why, just a preference. Hope it helps.

Comment: Can't you simply cast the output of values_list to list() rather than using the comprehension?
As in `usr_names = list(User.objects.all().values_list('username',flat=True))`

Answer (score 2):

As you wrote:

"but rather than a queryset (or list) of user objects"

Soulution above still queryset

```
usr_names = User.objects.all().values_list('username')
```

This solution:

```
usr_names = [str(elem) for elem in list(User.objects.all().values_list('username'))]
```

It will return a list of strings

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way you can get the list of objects of an attribute is to first get a query-set of that attribute alone using `values_list` then converting the django query-set to a python set using `set()` and finally to a list using `list()`.

In your scenario:

```py
user_names = list(set(User.objects.all().values_list('username', flat=True)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You replace 'field_name' with your own

`users_name = [i.field_name for i in Users.objects.all()]`

Answer (score 0):

To get the list and easily understands it since value list returns tuples in a list

```
users= User.objects.all().values_list("username")
usernames= []
for item in categories:
    usernames.append(item[0])
```